# On inverting navigation bar and footer contents

Tags: beamer, header-footer, themes, navigation, mini-frames

I'm using the `Frankfurt` theme in `beamer`. It includes a sort of navigation bar with (sub-)section titles and a circle per slide in each (sub-)section. I'd like to move such a bar to the bottom of the page and displaying the footer at the header place.

Do you know what should I do?

Edit:

1) How can I avoid to display that footer in the title slide?

2) How can I display the title of the presentation and the name of the author, say as in 
`Berlin` theme? I tried to use the suggested preamble using `Berlin` but it does not work.

Comment: I removed the thanks. It may seem a little odd, but this is just the style of TeX.sx. Thanks is best expressed by up voting answers as people try to help you.

Comment: `Frankfurt` alone doesn't produce any footer, since it uses the `smoothbars` outer theme which sets the `headline` template but doesn't set the `footline` template. How are you producing the footer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Frankfurt` uses the `smoothbars` outer theme which sets the `headline` template but doesn't set the `footline` template. To change the header position to the bottom of the frame, it's enough to set the `footline` template to behave exactly as `smoothbars` sets the headline template. To place the navigation symbols in the header, you need to redefine the `navigation symbols` template to do nothing and then to insert the symbols in the `headline` template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \pgfuseshading{beamer@barshade}%
  \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \vskip-9.75ex%
  \else%
    \vskip-7ex%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.25ex,dp=3.75ex]{section in head/foot}
    \insertnavigation{\paperwidth}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@sb@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.125ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}%
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\hskip1em\usebeamercolor[fg]{navigation symbols dimmed}%
\insertslidenavigationsymbol%
\insertframenavigationsymbol%
\insertsectionnavigationsymbol%
\insertsubsectionnavigationsymbol%
\insertdocnavigationsymbol%
\insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}    

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection one}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection two}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]