# Moving navigation symbols to footline of Beamer presentation with Berlin theme

Tags: beamer, header-footer, themes, navigation, mini-frames

I have exactly the style of navigation symbols that I would like for my Berlin themed Beamer presentation:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}
\makeatletter
\beamer@theme@subsectionfalse
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}{}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\beamer@compressfalse
\patchcmd{\insertnavigation}{\hskip-1.875ex plus-1fill}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\sectionentry}{\beamer@section@set@min@width}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\sectionentry}{\hskip1.875ex plus 1fill}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\sectionentry}{\hyperlink{Navigation#3}{{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}}}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\beamer@ypos=#2\relax}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\fakeslideentry}{\beamer@ypos=#2\relax}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\advance\beamer@tempdim by -.05cm{\advance\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@vboxoffset\advance\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@boxsize\advance\beamer@tempdim by 1.2\pgflinewidth}{}{}
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\kern\beamer@tempdim}{\advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt\advance\beamer@tempdim by\wd\beamer@sectionbox\kern\beamer@tempdim}{}{}
\makeatother

\author[sklum]{sklum} 
\title{mytitle}
\institute[myinst]{
institution \\
}

\begin{document}
\section{Sec00}
\subsection{Sec00} {
\begin{frame}{001}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{002}

\end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

Using the answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23151/beamer-infolines-outer-theme-with-miniframe-bullets-only-for-the-current-section) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88182/beamer-miniframes-side-by-side-section-names-and-navigation-dots/88403#88403), this code makes navigations symbols appear only for a section, and symbols appear directly to the right of the section title. However, I'd like to move the header containing the navigation symbols to the lowest part of the footer (i.e. below my name and the title). Unfortunately, the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35616/on-inverting-navigation-bar-and-footer-contents) does not work for the Berlin theme.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Berlin theme uses `miniframes` theme which has options to place author and institute in footline, but all navigation is defined to be in headline. Therefore you need to define a new `footline` template with title, author institute and navigation. This is what I did in next code. I've copied `headline` definition from `beamerouterthememiniframes.sty` and inserted after `footline` definition. Your patches also apply. You also need to use an empty `headline`.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\makeatletter
\beamer@theme@subsectionfalse
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamertemplate{mini frame in other subsection}{}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\makeatletter
\beamer@compressfalse
\patchcmd{\insertnavigation}{\hskip-1.875ex plus-1fill}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\sectionentry}{\beamer@section@set@min@width}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\sectionentry}{\hskip1.875ex plus 1fill}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\sectionentry}{\hyperlink{Navigation#3}{{\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}}}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\beamer@ypos=#2\relax}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\fakeslideentry}{\beamer@ypos=#2\relax}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\advance\beamer@tempdim by -.05cm}{\advance\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@vboxoffset\advance\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@boxsize\advance\beamer@tempdim by 1.2\pgflinewidth}{}{}
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\kern\beamer@tempdim}{\advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt\advance\beamer@tempdim by\wd\beamer@sectionbox\kern\beamer@tempdim}{}{}
\makeatother

\author[sklum]{sklum} 
\title{mytitle}
\institute[myinst]{
institution \\
}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
  {%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}%
      \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor}%
      \hfill%
      {\usebeamerfont{institute in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
      {\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\section{Sec00}
\subsection{Sec00} {
\begin{frame}{001}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{002}

\end{frame}
}
\section{Sec01}
\subsection{Sec01} {
\begin{frame}{001}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{002}

\end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]